# Convert reference to another type's reference (first_struct& to second_struct&) C++

Tags: c++

Consider my implementation returns types of

```
struct first_struct {  TKey key; TValue value;}
```

The interface (it's a homework) requests types of

```
struct pair { TKey first; TValue second;}
```

Me implementing the interface iterator:

```
...
pair& operator*() const {
    return *reinterpret_cast<pair*>(&*iter);  // smooth?
}

private:
Implementation::iter;  // operator* returns `first_struct&`, it's my implementation
```

Is this really the cleanest way to do this?
I also thought about making a conversion operator from `first_struct` to `pair&` but 1) first_struct should not care 2) in the operator, I have no idea how to point the data members of pair to the first_struct members' location, also pair by the assignment has data members as value types, not references.

EDIT:

This causes BAD_ACCESS, as it is, as Dan M. pointed out in comments, undefined behavior. [reinterpret_cast - cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)(I hope I understood it well)

BUT I looked at the standard draft (because at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) they mentioned (in Type aliasing paragraph) char is the exception, but nothing about char* (which I use elsewhere in the code in a similar situation).
In [standard draft - github](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4741.pdf)

> 8.5.1.10 Reinterpret cast
>
> § 7 An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue v of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is static_cast(static_cast(v)).
>
> § 11 A glvalue expression of type T1, designating an object x, can be cast to the type “reference to T2” if an expression of type “pointer to T1” can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to T2” using a reinterpret_cast. The result is that of *reinterpret_cast(p) where p is a pointer to x of type
>   “pointer to T1”.

And there's nothing about undefined behavior. If `static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` doesn't cause it (I hope). So it should work. Am I missing something or cppreference is wrong, or the standard is too new?

Comment: Why not `return reinterpret_cast<pair&>(*iter);`

Comment: Aha I should have known you can cast references too, that's better

Comment: That's UB and even if I works, it's very fragile.

Could you change your struct to hold references/pointers instead?

Comment: @DanM. maybe it would work, but in the assignment spec the pair has data members as value types, not references.

Comment: @Adam so you are storing `first_structs` but need to return `pair&` are you sure this problem can't be avoided in a saner way?

Comment: It seems your implementation doesn't match the API it should support. So, you should fix your implementation to use the `struct pair` instead. (This is the actual clean way I see.) If it happens in my daily work I use simple tricks to grant that software does not break due to such changes. In your case, I would remove `struct first_struct` and re-compile. The error list tells you exactly where you have to do the changes. (Unnecessary to mention search-and-replace.)

Comment: @DanM. I didn't realise that was UB. Because I thought that you can reinterpret_cast from char. And you indeed can: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast  But as you say, it is undefined behavior unless you're casting from char, new type is a similar type (just stripping basically all cv qualifiers) or new type a signed/unsigned version of the "old type". Though pointers are not explicitly mentioned - how they apply to Type aliasing if it's not char but char*. So this casting yields undefined behavior and indeed I get BAD ACCESS

Comment: @Adam if you have control over `first_struct` another workaround could be turning it into `struct first_struct : pair {}`. Not a great solution either though.

Comment: I'm going to solve it as @Scheff pointed out because I have to sacrifice my beliefs for a working homework. But still I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Hmm it's still not working maybe there's another problem. But the conflict between cppreference and the standard still exists

Comment: Did You try if it's possible to do ```std::pair<TKey&, TValue&>```?